# Migrosoft Teams mgraph REQUEST 401 SSL errror

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, user-presence

I encountered an error while importing microsoft teams data with precenesURL. I shared the URL information, python code and the error I encountered below. But,I don't get any error while retrieving UserDF info. I dont understand what was happened suddenly this code always works ,properly.
As I said , i can visualize UsersDF dataframe there is no mistake but presencesURL get error

> appId = 'xyz-bf9b-48c0-bafb-xyz89139f197'  clientSecret =
> '_az*************=' tokenUrl =
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xyz-1f64-4360-abc-601b4bb1b236/oauth2/token'
> usersUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999'
> presencesUrl =
> 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/getPresencesByUserId'
> tokenData = {  'grant_type': 'password',  'client_id': appId,
> 'client_secret': clientSecret,  'resource':
> 'https://graph.microsoft.com',  'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com',
> 'username':'abc@asa.com.tr',  'password':'abc2020!', }
>
> tokenReq = requests.post(tokenUrl, data=tokenData) token =
> tokenReq.json().get('access_token') usersDF = pd.DataFrame()
> userPresenceDF = pd.DataFrame() nRow = 100
>
> for i in range(math.ceil(len(usersDF)/nRow)):
>
> ```
> reqIds = '","'.join(str(i) for i in usersDF.iloc[i * 100:(i + 1) * 100,]['id'])
> reqBody = '''{
> "ids": ["''' + reqIds + '''"]
> }'''
>
> presencesReq= requests.post(presencesUrl, headers = {'Authorization': '{}'.format(token)}, json=json.loads(reqBody))
> ```
>
> print(presencesReq)

**Request[401] Error**

Comment: As you see in the document the presence URL is having the POST request, so you need to send the user id with the Presence URL. May be that causes the issue.
Ref Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples